# How to reference form's fields to add validators using NgForm, NgModel classes in angular2?

Tags: validation, angular, angularjs-ng-form, angular2-ngmodel

I want to add some **validation** to the fields of a form through *Validators* in Angular2:

- I'm binding **ngForm** to a form like this:

`#form="ngForm"`

- For the fields i'm binding **ngModel**:

`#field="ngModel", [(ngModel)]="model.field" type="text" name="field" placeholder="field"`

The [new form api](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) suggests to use ngForm and ngModel, but there is no documentation in angular.io docs how to use *Validators*.

In the [api reference to NgModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgForm-directive.html) there are properties like
`validator : ValidatorFn` and `asyncValidator : AsyncValidatorFn`

But i don't know **how to reference the fields from the component's class to add the validators**.

Comment: http://learnangular2.com/forms/

Comment: what kind of validators you need? ng2 supports out of the box "required" "pattern", "min length" so you can just add them to your inputs, and #form would be invalid if one if your inputs is invalid

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've followed the link that @rashfmnb pointed, it's what i was looking for.

Comment: I take that, the guide is outdated. [This one](http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/) is for rc4.